# Return integer value to js controller from Apex

Tags: apex, javascript

I have defined a method in the apex controller like below, I don't get any errors, but when loading the page it says **ERROR**

Here is the apex method:

```
public class Address_Penetration_ApexController {  
    @AuraEnabled
    public static integer getAddress_UnitCount() {       
        List<AggregateResult> count = [select COUNT(Id) from Address__c where Name like '%13750 100 Ave%'];
        return Integer.valueOf(count);
    }
}
```

Here is the JS Controller

```
({
    fetchAddress : function(component, event, helper) {
        var serverCall = component.get("c.getAddress_UnitCount");
        serverCall.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS"){
                var count = response.getReturnValue();
                console.log(count);
                component.set("v.totalUnits", count);    
            }else
                alert(state);        
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(serverCall);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The AggregateResult is not an Integer. Use COUNT() instead:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static integer getAddress_UnitCount() {       
    return [select COUNT() from Address__c where Name like '%13750 100 Ave%'];
}
```

Note you don't need the temporary variable or Integer.valueOf.

P.S. You should always use curly brackets, even if you don't need them. It makes your code more legible.

```
        }else {
            alert(state);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox